# Downloaded audio from Spotify cdn goes silent after 10 sec

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, spotify

I'm trying to fetch spotify audio from spotify cdn link:

> https://audio-fa.scdn.co/audio/cb1fb87a228...

but downloaded [audio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lEeavJpIUXfs7FCH3yRjBVSyybWPyb36/view?usp=sharing) is not more than 10 sec 
in network tab of browser saw spotify fetch music over one url with different range
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foKrl.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If3vc.png)
so decided to use python request module inorder to set **Range** in header but it doesn’t work either:

```
import requests

local_filename = "music"
with requests.get(
        'https://audio-fa.scdn.co/audio/cb1fb87a',
        headers={
            'Range': 'bytes=0-6583015',    
        }
) as r:
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
        print('done')
```

Comment: This is probably a preventative method Spotify has to stop people from downloading their music... I'm pretty sure that downloading music as an mp3 or anything other than the download feature built into Spotify premium is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

This is done on purpose, Spotify has a built in copy protection. Both the streams and the cached files are encrypted making it harder than simply downloading the audio file and head, merging them together and using that. To my knowledge the head is not encrypted and the streams are, the audio format is ogg/vorbis, I don't know for sure how the encryption works, and I don't think it's legal to break it and get your music for free but it should be possible if you can reverse engineer what encryption is used and where to find the keys. If you want to download your music I suggest looking for it from other sources that have higher quality if you don't have Spotify premium.